# MWE: Cannot load ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, firefox, es6-modules

I'm trying to use ES6 modules in Firefox, but it does not work (WTF:
unless loading from disk). I've boiled it down to this MWE, but can't
see anything wrong with it:

HTML `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>title</title>

    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <p id="status">failed</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Module `file.js`

```
export const x = 42;
```

Main script `main.js`

```
import { x } from './file.js';

window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById('status').textContent = x;

};
```

Now, all these files are served correctly by NGINX:

```
$ cmp main.js <(curl 'localhost:8080/main.js' 2>/dev/null)
$ cmp file.js <(curl 'localhost:8080/file.js' 2>/dev/null)
$ cmp index.html <(curl 'localhost:8080/index.html' 2>/dev/null)
```

But it does not work in Firefox. Going to `http://localhost:8080/` in
Firefox does not start the script, and on its Console it displays only
this message:

```
Loading failed for the module with source “http://localhost:8080/main.js”. localhost:8080:7
```

Without further info.

The Network tab shows that `main.js` is loaded, but `file.js` is not
even tried (i.e., it does not fail loading).

Of course, `dom.moduleScripts.enabled;true` in `about:config`.

Surprisingly, it works if I let FF load that stuff directly:

```
$ firefox index.html
```

Shows the `42` I was expecting to see.

Versions used:

- Firefox Quantum 62.0 (64-bit), all add-ons disabled and restarted browser.

  ```
  $ firefox -version
  Mozilla Firefox 62.0
  ```

  - NGINX

    $ nginx -v
    nginx version: nginx/1.14.0

Comment: It works fine for me on FF, served by Apache. What happens when you type `http://localhost:8080/main.js` into the address bar and press enter?

Comment: It shows the script as expected, nothing suspicious.  Luckily I had
the Console open, which said: “The character encoding of the plain
text document was not declared. [...] The character encoding of the
file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol [...]”

It has nothing to do with the encoding, but it turned out nginx served
the scripts as `text/plain`.  I have changed that to `text/javascript`
and now it works.  Changed to `text/javascript; charset=utf-8` also
works and is probably better.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `Content-Type` header from the HTML server.  Changing that solved the problem.  It must be `text/javascript`.  Thanks to Chris G for the helpful comment.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, different scenario: I've used webpack and I got identical warning in Firefox console because I've linked my script, not a bundle file.

Newbie mistake, but *errare humenum est*. Maybe helps someone.